# Unable to read pdf content using Selenium Webdriver./PDFBox. Getting java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File Exception message

Tags: java, selenium, pdfbox

I am working on web page, where clicking on a link opens a pdf file on the same window.  I have to read that pdf file content to validate  some data. I don't want to download the pdf to read the content. I need to read content from browser itself.  From the url how I can validate that the file opened is a pdf file. Using latest Chrome browser version. Can anyone help me on this?

Here the URL doesn't ends with .pdf extension.
Sample pdf url: blob:https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/15946946-ca67-40eb-abd5-3fd8d477519d

Sample Code :

```
String currentRawURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        String[] currentURL = currentRawURL.split("blob:");
        String PDFURL = currentURL[1];
        URL url = new URL(PDFURL);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream fileParse = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(fileParse);
        PDFTextStripper pdf = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pdfContent = pdf.getText(document);
        document.close();
        System.out.println(" PDF Content  : " +pdfContent);
        // TestNG assertion for checking if text is present in content
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("test"));
```

Console Output:

```
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1119)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2497)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2468)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:233)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1144)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1041)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: assuming that the URL responds with a file you can use  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(fileURL), new File(path+filename));: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile

Comment: please post the whole stack trace.

Comment: I think that error usually comes from an unclosed stream.  Download the file first.  Then read it.

Comment: That stacktrace usually means that the PDF is an empty file. To verify this, copy the content of the stream into a file.

Comment: @Ramaranjan - You're issue was solved? If yes, Can you please help me? I am seeing same issue.